# How catch icon value,change value and color using semantic ui react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, semantic-ui

Using semantic ui ,
Initialize the prop at father component :  isFavorite = false
can't catch the value after clickig at icon , how i fill the star to diff color (by add attribute?
`styleColor={isFavorite : color:"red" : color:"white"`
})

**component.js**
const ProductDetails = () => {

```
    const {productId} = useParams()
    
    const selectedProd = useSelector((state) => state.allProducts.products.find(product => 
        product.id === parseInt(productId)
        ));
    const products = useSelector((state) => state.allProducts.products)
    
  
    let {isFavorite} = selectedProd 
   
   
   const handleFavoriteSelect =(e)=>{
        isFavorite = !isFavorite
        selectedProd.isFavorite=isFavorite  
        dispatch(updateProducts(products,selectedProd))            

   }

return(
     <i onClick={e => handleFavoriteSelect(e)} className="right floated star outline icon" onChange={e=> console.log(!e.target.attributes.value)} value={isFavorite}></i>
)
```

**redux/action.js**

```
export const updateProducts = (products,product) => {
    const indexOfItem = products.findIndex(q => q.id === product.id);
    if (indexOfItem > -1) {
        products[indexOfItem] = product;
     }
    return {
        type: ActionTypes.SET_PRODUCTS,
        payload: products
    };
};
```

**redux/reducer.js**

```
export const productReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
   
    switch (type) {
        case ActionTypes.SET_PRODUCTS:
            //take state and update this with payload data
            return {...state,products:payload};
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

**redux/reducer/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { productReducer,selectedProductReducer } from './productReducer'

const reducers = combineReducers({
    allProducts: productReducer,
    product:selectedProductReducer
})

export default reducers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
style={isFavorite?{color:"red"}:{color:"white"}}
```

I would suggest an edit to changing the product as well, you are currently mutating state like you've never read a line of documentation about [redux](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) or react:

```
//toggleFavorite would be much more descriptive
const handleFavoriteSelect =(e)=>{
  dispatch(updateProducts(products,{
    ...selectedProd,
    isFavorite:!selectedProd.isFavorite
  }))   
}

export const updateProducts = (products, product) => {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.SET_PRODUCTS,
    payload: products.map(
      (currentProduct) =>
        currentProduct.id === product,id
          ? product //return changed product
          : currentProduct //return original product
    ),
  };
};
```

That still leaves you with way too much logic in your component and action creator, it would be better to define a TOGGLE_FAVORITE action type with the id as payload and let the reducer handle the logic of toggling favorite.

Comment: just currentProduct.id === product.id :) thanks